# Can't use a DataSet in a class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm modifying an application in C# with Visual Studio 2010 (I haven't developed it, just modified). I have added a DataSet called DSSolucion to get the DB data but I can't use it in a class because I get the following error:
*The type or namespace name 'DSSolucion' does not exist in the namespace 'CCTV.DataSets' (are you missing an assembly reference?)*
I have build and rebuild the solution with no results.
Any idea?
(There is a CCTV.dll file in the bin folder, I don't know if I have to do sonething with it).
Thanks very much.

Comment: add the reference of cctv.dll in the project

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure you have added the using clause at top of class

**using System.Data;**